# text-align: center; not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, text-align

I have this HTML

```
<section id="selection">
<a href="shop.html#shopBags"><img src="img/coverpictures/frontpage01.jpg"></a>
<a href="shop.html#shopAttachments"><img src="img/coverpictures/frontpage02.jpg"></a>
<a href="shop.html#shopAccessories"><img src="img/coverpictures/frontpage03.jpg"></a>
</section>
```

With this CSS

```
#selection{
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  text-align: -moz-center;
  word-spacing: 4vw;
  margin: 0;
}

#selection img{
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I want the three links/images to be centered in the div. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari the pictures float right. How do I fix this?

Comment: euh, and about `test-align:center` within the container instead of the img ? also remove the other ones ..

Comment: Its a bug from safari, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40216 from 2010 until now.

Comment: @Troyer what ?? are you joking ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#selection{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    }
```

Comment: for image give margin:auto

Comment: It works with margin:auto. I think it was the letter-spacing that messed with it. How do I get spacing between the images without messing with the centering?

Comment: padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;  you can give your own padding

Comment: @S.Drescher did you simply try `text-align:center` without any prefix ??